# Samsung SSD initial state

Tags: ssd, docking-station

I bought two Samsung 850 EVO SSDs to install in two Macs (which are not available here). As a test I used a docking station (this one: https://www.amazon.co.uk/CiT-inch-Aluminium-Docking-Station/dp/B00FSCR97W/ref=sr_1_1?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1468343948&sr=1-1) but nothing is detected on Linux or Windows7. Only the docking station is detected and even then it doesn't identify:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0644:0200 TEAC Corp. All-In-One Multi-Card Reader CA200/B/S 
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 413c:3016 Dell Computer Corp. Optical 5-Button Wheel Mouse
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 413c:1003 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard Hub
Bus 005 Device 004: ID 413c:2010 Dell Computer Corp. Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 1f75:0621
```

The last entry above is the docking station.  Does this indicate a faulty docking station or am I expecting too much; are the SSDs not formatted or some such?

**EDIT**

Using `lsblk` instead of `lsusb` gives:

```
$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 698.7G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 694.7G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
sdf      8:80   0 111.8G  0 disk
```

The last entry is 111.8G, which is a bit small for a 120GB SSD. Is it correct?

**EDIT** *Conclusion*

So it turns out that the SSDs are not formatted on delivery.  `fdisk` shows the device to be 120GB and can be used to create a partition table. `mkdosfs` can be used to create a filesystem and the device then mounts and works.

Comment: What do you hope to prove by connecting these drives to a Linux/Windows machine in an enclosure?

Comment: Just to see whether they work, as in whether I can access them. If not I can send them back. I am in London now, but I live in Ecuador so once I go back there sending back becomes difficult.

Comment: Did you purchase them new?

Comment: The empty field does NOT necessarily means the docking station or the SSD is not working. You should not use `lsusb` to test what you want to know. You should check whether `lsblk` shows an extra `sdX` with correct capacity of the SSD when connected.

Comment: @Ramhound - yes, new.

Comment: @TomYan - thanks. I updated the post to include the output of `lsblk`. It shows 112GB which is a bit small for a 120GB device (same for both SSDs).

Comment: @WilliamMorris 120GB is `111.75870895385742` GiB. See http://wintelguy.com/gb2gib.html for more info.

Comment: It is correct. According to the [IDEMA Standard LBA 1-03](http://idema.org/?page_id=2172), a 120GB SSD should have 234441648 logical blocks if its logical block size is 512-byte, while 234441648 * 512 / (1024 ^ 3) = 111.79GiB

Comment: You can check the exact number of blocks/sectors with `fdisk -l` or `sg_readcap` in sg3_utils btw. However, note that the capacity being reported correctly does NOT necessarily guarantee the drive is going to work fine when you perform read/write operation on it. To test it (a bit more) thoroughly you should probably at least partition and format the drive as well.

Comment: @TomYan - thanks again. `fdisk` works and writes the partition table.